# SPARQL Filter Date VALUES

Tags: datetime, filter, sparql

I have created an RDF dataset in protege having dates of type "datetime" (I have not found option of creating simple dates)

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ?date
 WHERE {
   ?p ex:date ?date. 
   VALUES ?date {  2022-07-27T00:00:00  } 
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined namespace prefix at 'T00' before ':00'
```

Is there a way to use VALUES to filter dates? I tried to use string as the type of the dates in protege' but I am still cannot filter dates using 'VALUES' in the SPARQL query.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved after putting the literal in double quotes and also adding the datatype I needed as follows:

```
SELECT ?date
 WHERE {
   ?p ex:date ?date. 
   VALUES ?date {   "2022-07-27"^^<w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>  } 
}
```

Comment: You probably changed it to be able to post it, but as a heads-up to others reading this solution: The datatype URI needs to be absolute, e.g., `^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>`. Or, if you define the `xsd:` prefix: `^^xsd:dateTime`.